# Hooks equivalent for componentWilLReceiveProps to update state

Tags: reactjs

So I have a component where I conditionally update state on props change. If current state's CurrentPage is not equal to next props CurrentPage, I update state with next props' CurrentPage:

```
public componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (this.state.CurrentPage !== nextProps.CurrentPage) {
        this.setState({ CurrentPage: nextProps.CurrentPage });
    }
}
```

I'm in the middle of refactoring the component do use hooks. I have a useState hook setup for CurrentPage when the component first loads:

`const [currentPage, setCurrentPage]` = useState(props.CurrentPage ? props.CurrentPage : 1);

What would be the hook equivalent of the `componentWillReceiveProps` logic in this case? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to change state based on prop change when you can just use that prop directly, since they are the same properties? react does not recommend this https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#when-to-use-derived-state

Comment: because i need to perform some internal logic based on the prop update in my state.

Comment: read the useEffect hook documentation.

Answer (score 14):

use the "useEffect" hook for such purposes.

```
 useEffect(() => {
if(props.yourproperty){ 
//execute your code.
}
   console.log('property changed', props.yourproperty);
 },[props.yourproperty])
```

This will only be called in case props.yourproperty is changed so no need to check with old props.

[UseEffect Hook docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

Comment: So can I potentially do `setCurrentPage(props.CurrentPage)` in the place you have console log?

Comment: yes exactly, the best part this would only be executed in case CurrentPage property is changed. It gives you much finer control

Comment: What if my `props.CurrentPage` is an optional prop? In my test I don't set `props.CurrentPage` but it looks like `useEffect` is still being called - I thought it would only get called on subsequent prop changes if I have `[props.CurrentPage]` specified...?

Comment: it will be called atleast once, have edited the answer

Comment: you just need to check for undefined inside the use effect.

Answer (score 1):

You'll utilize the `useEffect()` hook. For an explanation of why, please read my guide to understand the hook and how you can leverage it: [React Hooks Guide - useEffect](https://jzmqvzzq0w.codesandbox.io/hooks#useeffect) (give it some time to load, codesandbox is a bit slow).

Your example is a bit arbitrary, as your `props` will already contain the current page, but nevertheless, here's a working example...

**Working example** (props updating another component's state):

[image: Edit Simple Page Monitor]

---

**components/Navigation**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { Link, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

const style = {
  marginRight: 5
};

const Navigation = ({ location: { pathname }, children }) => {
  // initializing "currentPage" with the current "pathname" prop
  // initializing "setPage" function to update "currentPage"
  const [currentPage, setPage] = useState(pathname);

  // utilizing useEffect to keep track of "pathname" changes 
  // that, upon change, will update the "currentPage" state
  useEffect(() => {
    setPage(pathname);
  }, [pathname]);

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="nav">
        <Link style={style} to="/">
          Home
        </Link>
        <Link style={style} to="/page1">
          Page 1
        </Link>
        <Link style={style} to="/page2">
          Page 2
        </Link>
      </div>
      <div className="page">
        <p>
          (current page: <strong>{currentPage}</strong> )
        </p>
      </div>
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};

Navigation.propTypes = {
  pathname: PropTypes.string
};

export default withRouter(Navigation);
```

Comment: i understand that by passing `pathname` as the first item in the array, it will look for changes in that value. but why are you passing `setPage` as the second item in the array?

Comment: Sorry, that was typo. Fixed. However, if the function is `memoized` via `useCallback` or `useMemo` and it's being utilized within `useEffect`, then it also needs to be added to the `[dependencies]` as well. If you use the `create-react-app` they've added an `exhaustive-deps` eslint rule to throw a warning about missing dependencies.

Comment: What if my `props.CurrentPage` is an optional prop? In my test I don't set `props.CurrentPage` but it looks like `useEffect` is still being called - I thought it would only get called on subsequent prop changes if I have `[props.CurrentPage]` specified...?

Comment: Youll need to add a conditional statement in that case. For example, in my “setInterval timer” example, I utilize a ref to conditionally “autoStart” the timer. It sounds like you may need to do this as well. To see the example, scroll to the bottom of the “useRef” explanation in my guide that I linked above.